# Duplicate rows in a Mysql table with amended strings

Tags: mysql

I am trying to cycle through a table of records and for every record - inert a new record with some modified values.

So I have the following table (about 100,000 records):

```
+------+-------------+----------------+
|  ID  |  meta_key   |   meta_value   |
+------+-------------+----------------+
|   1  |  img_url    |  test.jpg      |
|   2  |  img_url    |  test2.jpg     |
|   3  |  img_url    |  test3.jpg     |
+------+-------------+----------------+
```

I want to end up with the following:

```
+------+-------------+----------------+
|  ID  |  meta_key   |   meta_value   |
+------+-------------+----------------+
|   1  |  img_url    |  test.jpg      |
|   2  |  img_url    |  test2.jpg     |
|   3  |  img_url    |  test3.jpg     |
|   4  |  new_url    |  {test.jpg}    |
|   5  |  new_url    |  {test2.jpg}   |
|   6  |  new_url    |  {test3.jpg}   |
+------+-------------+----------------+
```

So I'm getting all my original records, looping through them and creating a new record foreach where I will slightly change the meta_value by adding some text at the beginning and at the end of the original meta_value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO table (meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT 'new_url' as meta_key, CONCAT('{', meta_value, '}') from table
```

assuming that your ID is AI

Comment: CONCATA should be CONCAT? - Changed that and it worked. Thanks!